# querying an sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

So I am querying a database that is called golfDB and it consists of one table called players with 5 fields:

- name (player's name)
- totalGross (sum of the gross scores from each round)
- totalRounds (number of rounds played)
- pars (total number of pars made)
- birdies (total number of birdies made)

The function I'm working on is supposed to list the players in descending order according to their average score (totalGross/ totalRounds).

I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this, my code is currently separating all the components (players, total gross score, and total rounds) into their own lists.  I was thinking then I could divide each total gross score list item by each item in the total rounds list, but I'm not really sure how to then link those scores back to their corresponding player so that they can be ordered.

I don't know if it is even possible to do it this way, so does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

```
def queryDBplayers(cursor):
    """lists the players in order of their total gross score"""
    cursor.execute('select name, totalGross, totalRounds from players')
    answer= cursor.fetchall()
    players = list()
    for items in answer:
        players.append(items[0])
    totalGrossScore = list()
    for items in answer:
        totalGrossScore.append(items[1])
    totalRoundsScore = list()
    for items in answer:
        totalRoundsScore.append(items[2])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this *far* more complicated than it needs to be.

Firstly, I don't understand why you're mucking around with separate lists. If you have a single list of players you can sort them very simply with a key function:

```
players.sort(key=lambda p: float(p[1]) / float(p[2]))
```

But, you really shouldn't be doing this in Python at all. The best place to do sorting is in the database:

```
SELECT name, totalGross, totalRounds ORDER BY totalGross/totalRounds
```

As with your previous question, it seems that you would benefit from learning some basic SQL.

Comment: I think he probably needs to cast those to decimal in the query (+1 all the same) otherwise he will get truncated ints i suspect wich will mess up the sort

Comment: Yeah, I don't know much about SQL. This is for a class and we're supposed to be learning it mostly on our own but I'm having a really hard time understanding it.  I didn't realize that you could do the actual division in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute('select name, totalGross, totalRounds from players')
answer= cursor.fetchall()

print sorted(answer,key=lambda x:float(x[1])/float(x[2]))
```

I would think would work ... I dont know but you might be able to craft the query to sort this for you

on a side note its easier to separate the columns like `col1,col2,col3 = zip(*big_list)` in your case this would be

```
players,grosses,rounds = zip(*answer)
```